# How to send user from example.com/category.php?id_category=19 to example.com/index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to redirect

example.com/category.php?id_category=19&orderby=name&orderway=asc&id_lang=2

to

example.com/index.php?id_lang=2 (id_lang should be same like above value)

when using .htaccess and mod_rewrite?

I am pretty sure this is basic stuff when writing rewrite rules, so it is probably easy-peasy for some experienced programmer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rules... :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} category\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id_category\=19\&orderby\=name\&orderway\=asc\&id_lang\=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?id_lang=%1
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: hmm, still not working, when espcaping special characters like dots and slashes, do you need the quotes or not for the whole string?

Comment: What about underscores? Should they be a problem? I mean id_lang and maybe the and charactter !7!) is problem too

Comment: i tried with my domain and it is working find...  can you please post your .htaccess file content?